# How to add actions to menu buttons in floating action button in android

Tags: android, android-activity, onclicklistener, submenu, floating-action-button

I am trying to create a floating action button in android and want to add actions to those small sub buttons to start new activity by clicking them.  I successfully managed to create those sub buttons but cannot assign action to them to start new activity.

Comment: Add related code snippet.

Comment: I'm nut sure how you achieving but you can look at [this](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/getbase/floatingactionbutton/sample/MainActivity.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i have understand what you want to do.. but seems you want simple open a new activity onClick.. so you can do in this way:

```
Button floatingBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fab);
floatingBtn.setOnClickListener = new(view.onClickListener()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);

});
```

Remember to insert the new activity in the manifest